# BLOB to byte array conversion in  objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios4, arrays, blob

I have a table filed in which the value is stored as **BLOB** type . I need to get that as  a binary array so that I can get different values from different byte positions in the BLOB. Any Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Get the start and length of the blob.
// (remember column indexes are 0-based when fetching the value
//  but 1-base when binding - yeah cheers!)
uint8_t *data = (uint8_t *)sqlite3_column_blob(stmt, columnIndex);
size_t length = (size_t)sqlite3_column_bytes(stmt, columnIndex);

// And now you can access the data

unsigned sum = 0;
for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
    sum += data[i];
```